# Improve password security in server verification

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently building a setup to take credit card information. The following structure was used:

**Server 1:**

- MySQL user set to read only
- Holds the login credentials.

I use PBKDF2 hashing, done with a class i built based on [this code](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode).

**Server 2:**

- MySQL user set to read and write
- holds all of the customers credit card information

**My question:**

If server 1 stores the paswword in this format: **algorithm:iterations:salt:hash**

For example: `sha256:1000:Pe27BkIKkBHklogp9Io80iRKtF+6koly:nrYUwOlixwJECRcjBRKwQ+MVNMTbnYnm`

If server one was compromised, it seems to me that having the password in this format would make it easy for them to crack the passwords for the site and access the users credit card information.

Is this a case where I need to use Mysql (**AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT()**)?

Am I over thinking this?

Is there a better way to protect the information in server 1?

**Update Based on Comments**

I built my heating and air company system. Any one that pays online can store their cc information with quickbooks if they choose. I have a few larger clients that we bill monthly in office, and process cc's through a desktop terminal. These clients have customer profiles on our servers, which they can access. These are the clients that I want to allow to store there cc information. This way I don't have to have the cc information stored on paper in our office for anyone to find.

Comment: You need to read the PCI documentation and be compliant with it, if indeed you're *storing credit card information*.

Comment: I do not actually do the cc processing. I only need to store the information on my company system, for future payments, which are done through quickbooks online

Comment: It's irrelevant whether you're doing the processing or not, PCI compliance is about storing CC details

Comment: In most cases credit card processors offer vault type services to store credit card details for 1-click or recurring purchases.  You should really look into this and stay out of the credit card data storage game.

Comment: @MikeBrant and others, please read the edit I made. This may help you understand what I am trying to do. Also the servers are ours, if this makes any difference in your thought's..... Thanks for your input.

Comment: I am agree with @MikeBrant - it is better to use some processor, because payment systems have a lot of requirements for such data. As I know, in most cases, if someone store something like credit card information, they use dedicated server that only responses "correct" or "not correct" to requests. And, of course, it should be isolated at maximum

Comment: @ROYFinley It doesn't make any difference in my comments.  What is the difference in having the credit card numbers lying around on paper vs. having them in a database? Either way people (including yourself) have access to them. You could in fact jeopardize your status with your credit card processor if you do not store such data in a PCI compliant way.  Trying to establish PCI compliance is going to probably take 10x the effort of simply using a vault type of service.

Comment: I have access to them all now, I just don't want any of the employee's to be able to get there hands on them. Our office was broken into three weeks ago.... this is what sent me down this path.

Comment: @MikeBrant, lets say that we replace credit card information with... user information. Then could you give me your thought on how the password is being stored in Server one. This system has been in place for a while now, for the customer to view invoices. Until looking into the cc storage, I never thought about the way that the password was stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, if I manage to compromise server 1, I'm not going to try to crack those passwords. They should be secure.  What I would more likely do is try to get my own code installed on the server to send me the passwords and/or credit card information when the user logs in.  For example, let's say you process the authentication in a file named login.php.  If I can compromise login.php, then when it is validating the login, I can have it execute a curl command or something to send the login information to my own server where I can collect it.

But I digress...  The answer is that your hashing of the user login details should be secure as you've described it.  If server 1's database is compromised, it should be about as secure as it can be.  You could add a layer of obfuscation within your PHP code to do something like munge in the a hash of the salt or something so that someone with access to the database but not the code would have a much harder time knowing what process you used to hash the passwords, which would avoid hackers from trying to brute force passwords such as password, iloveu, etc.  I would also *highly* suggest that the credit card information on server 2 is stored in an encrypted format using either `AES_ENCRYPT()` or PHP's [`mcrypt_encrypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) function.

Make sure you sanitize *all* input via POST forms, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, if I do this, I will definitely encrypt the cc's. For now I have them stored in a word document in a TrueCrypt drive on my computer. I only have 46 customer That we bill in this manner.....maybe not worth the effort to go further. but it would be nice if they could update their cc information on there user profile . Anyway Thanks for the Input